# DropDownListFor() not setting to the model value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm looping over my model but the value that is coming from the model isn't what's showing in the drop down list as the selected item. Instead the list is always just showing the first entry.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.RecordType, Model.RecordTypes, new { id="recordType_" + item.TransactionID })
```

item.RecordType has a value of 5 from the model (I print it out so I know it's that value). However the drop down shows "Initial" (which is a value of 4) instead of "Firm" (which is the valu eof 5 which is what our model item value is). The list in the source is defined as:

```
<select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field RecordType must be a number." id="recordType_63" name="item.RecordType">
<option value="4">Initial</option>
<option value="5">Firm</option>
<option value="6">Announced</option>
<option value="7">N/A</option>
</select>
```

How do I set the drop down to be what the model value is?

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RecordTypes
        {
            //get { return new SelectListItem(recordTypes, "RECORD_TYPE_ID", "RECORD_TYPE");  }
            get
            {
                return (from r in recordTypes
                        select new SelectListItem { Text = r.RECORD_TYPE, Value = r.RECORD_TYPE_ID.ToString() });
            }
        }
```

Comment: How do you construct `Model.RecordTypes`?

Comment: Edited answer to show that. The thing that I noticed is that SelectListItem takes 2 strings. My records have the value as integers. Is the mismatch causing the issue? What's the best way to handle that because I would imagine in all databases these things id's would be stored as integers because they are, but in html it seems they are treated as strings. In the view I can't do a ToString() on my model item as it errors on me saying you can't alter the model like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by creating a [`SelectList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) in your `Html.DropDownListFor` like:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.RecordType, new SelectList(Model.RecordTypes, item.RecordType), new { id="recordType_" + item.TransactionID });
```

This passes your `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` into the constructor along with a parameter, in this case `item.RecordType`, letting it know which item to select.

---

EDIT: In response to comment

You could use the overload of `SelectList` which allows you to specify the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` in your case these would be `Text` and `Value` respectively.

or

Re-work your `Model.RecordTypes` to return a `SelectList` and do the necessary work in there, you could use a method and pass in the value to select. Something like:

```
public SelectList RecordTypes(object selectedValue)
{
    return new SelectList(recordTypes, "RECORD_TYPE", "RECORD_TYPE_ID", selectedValue);
}
```

---

Hope that helps.

Comment: This seems logical, but what I'm getting is a listbox where all the values are: "System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem".

Comment: This worked! I guess at this point then I can return the actual list type from the model instead of converting it to SelectList() and in the view I would put the id/value column of the actual model. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your last edit won't work because I can have multiple records that need to display this (I'm looping over my model of item.RecordType. So doing it inside the view is required and works like you have in your first example.

Answer (score 1):

When you are assembling your `RecordTypes` `SelectListItem` collection, make sure to set `Selected = true` for the currently selected item-- it will not set it for you.

Assuming the `RecordType` variable on your view model mates up against the `RECORD_TYPE_ID` variable of your data set, you can update creation of variable to:

```
from r in recordTypes
select new SelectListItem { Text = r.RECORD_TYPE, Value = r.RECORD_TYPE_ID.ToString(), Selected = r.RECORD_TYPE_ID == this.RecordType }
```

If you are re-using the `RecordTypes` variable across multiple dropdowns on the view, you're going to have to change your approach and create the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` for each dropdown. Suchas:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.RecordType, RecordTypes.Select(rt => new SelectListItem { Text = rt.Text, Value = rt.Value, Selected = rt.Value == item.RecordType}))
```

Comment: That collection isn't assembled for each record. It's assembled once and passed to the view. I can have x number of records showing this drop down box and they would all have different values for this so setting it at the RecordTypes assembly doesn't seem like it would work.